# How to start slaves on different machines in spring remote partitioning strategy

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am using spring batch local partitioning to process my Job.In local partitioning multiple slaves will be created in same instance i.e in the same job. How Remote partitioning is different from local partitioning.What i am assuming is that in Remote partitioning each slave will be executed in different machine. Is my understanding correct. If my understanding is correct how to start the slaves in different machines without using cloudfoundry. I have seen Michael Minella talk on Remote partitioning https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYTj5YT7CZU tutorial. I am curious to know how remote partitioning works without using cloudfoundry. How can I start slaves in different machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While that video uses CloudFoundry, the premise of how it works applies off CloudFoundry as well.  In that video I launch multiple JVM processes (web apps in that case).  Some are configured as slaves so they listen for work.  The other is configured as a master and he's the one I use to do the actual launching of the job.

Off of CloudFoundry, this would be no different than deploying WAR files onto Tomcat instances on multiple servers.  You could also use Spring Boot to package executable jar files that run your Spring applications in a web container.  In fact, the code for that video (which is available on Github here: https://github.com/mminella/Spring-Batch-Talk-2.0) can be used in the same way it was on CF.  The only change you'd need to make is to not use the CF specific connection factories and use traditional configuration for your services.

In the end, the deployment model is the same off CloudFoundry or on.  You launch multiple JVM processes on multiple machines (connected by middleware of your choice) and Spring Batch handles the rest.